# Allow user to input first and last name; display full name back to user (first + last)

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I know this is something really simple but I can't figure out what I'm missing or doing wrong. I think it might be something with the char variables. This is what I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
char fname[20],lname[20];

cout<<"Please enter your First Name:";
cin>>"fname";
cout<<"Please enter your Last Name:";
cin>>"lname";

cout<<"Your full name is:"<<fname<<lname<<endl;

int a,b = 0;

for(a=0;a<=50;a++) 
{ 
if(a%3!=0&&a%4!=0&&a%5!=0) 
{ 
printf(" %d",a);
b++;
} 
} 
printf("\nNos of counts%d",b); 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cin>>"fname";
```

You are trying to extract into the string literal `"fname"`. It seems you meant to extract into the variable `fname`:

```
cin>>fname;
```

Comment: I'm exactly like Einstein. Don't forget to accept the answer when you can.

Answer (score 0):

Just going to make a couple suggestions since Joseph answered the question. Add a space between first and last name so it's not printing there name as one word.

```
cout <<"Your full name is: "<< fname << ' '  << lname << endl;
```

when declaring b to 0, you didn't assign a to anything.

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
```

and cout is much more powerful than printf, you shouldn't use C syntax in C++ unless there is no other option.

```
cout << a << ' ';
```

and

```
cout  << "\nNos of counts " << b;
```

Comment: Thanks, I put those in. Theres a 21 at the end of the program, anybody know how to get rid of it?
int main()
{ 
 char fname[20],lname[20];

 cout<<"...ter your First Name:";
 cin>>fname;
 cout<<"Please enter your Last Name:";
 cin>>lname;
 cout<<endl;
 cout<<"Your full name is:"<<' '<<fname<<' '<<lname<<endl;
 cout<<endl;
 cout<<"Below is the list of integer numbers from 1 through 50 which does not contain the divisible by 3, 4 and 5 numbers:"<<endl;
 cout<<endl;
 int a = 0, b = 0;

 for(a = 0; a <= 50; a++) 
 { 
 if(a%3!=0&&a%4!=0&&a%5!=0) 
 { 
 cout<<a<<' ';
 b++; 
 } 
 } 
 cout<<b<<endl;
}

Comment: are you still encountering this problem?